# How to set default folder of php in netbeans?

Tags: php, netbeans

On running php project in netbeans opens the URL `localhost/html/ProjectName/file.php`. I should correct this every time by removing `html/`. Is there any setting to change the default folder to run in netbeans? I save project in `/var/www/html`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

right click on the project in netbeans

go to run configuration and change the project URL so it satisfy your need (without html)

[image]